# How add "Add new" option of the custom post types in plugin menus?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show a custom post type "Add new" menu to the plugin menu added by using the "add_menu_page".

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I have registered the post type using the code "register_post_type",  then added a menu using "add_menu_page" function. The "show_in_menu" argument of the   "register_post_type" set as menu_slug of add_menu_page

Comment: can you post your arguments of `register_post_type`

Comment: $args = array(   
         'labels'    => $labels,        
         'public'   => true,
   'publicly_queryable'=> true,
   'show_ui'           => true,
   'show_in_menu'      => 'test_slug',
   'query_var'         => true,
   'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'test'),
   'capability_type'   => 'post',
   'has_archive'       => true,
   'hierarchical'      => false,
   'menu_position'     => null,
   'supports'          => array( 'title')
  );

Comment: post your `$labels,` array

Comment: array('name'=> _x( 'Tests', 'post type general name', 'wp-test' ),'singular_name' => _x( 'Test', 'post type singular name', 'wp-test' ),'menu_name' => _x( 'Tests', 'admin menu', 'wp-test' ),'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Tests', 'add new on admin bar', 'wp-test' ),'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'test', 'wp-test' ),'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Test', 'wp-test' ),'new_item' => __( 'New Test', 'wp-test' ),'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Test', 'wp-test' ),'view_item' => __( 'View Test', 'wp-test' ),'all_items'=> __( 'All Tests', 'wp-test' ),'search_items' => __( 'Search Tests',

Comment: 'wp-test'),'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Tests:', 'wp-test' ),'not_found' => __( 'No Test found.', 'wp-test' ),'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Test found in Trash.', 'wp-test' ));

Answer (score 1):

I have used the function **add_submenu_page()** and configured the "**Add New**" options to plugin menu and added the menu slug as "*post-new.php?post_type=test*"